# Coloring of User Types in Visual Studio 2008 and the future 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I really have an issue with Visual Studio's support for coloring User Types in VB.NET, I'm an C# developer that have been forced to code in Vb.NET by political rules in my organization, and I really misses the support for coloring user types in Vb.NET, I had hoped that this would be solved in Visual Studio 2010 and well in the beta they have added Vb.NET User Type coloring, but the coloring is the same for all user types I cant't have one color for interfaces and one for classes and so on.

Are there anyone that know any addin that can solve this for me nicely because it seems that Microsoft aren't helping me here :P.

Comment: the tool/options setting don't meet you needs?

Answer (score 2):

I do think Resharper for VB.Net does this.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/index.html

Enable code analysis / color identifiers in the resharper options, et voila!

There's a 30days trial.

My condolences for your recent VB migration.

Cheers,
Florian

Answer (score 1):

In 2008 there is no support for user defined type colorization and I don't know of any specific Add-In / Package which supports this.  It's one of those features which was requested but fell off the schedule for various reasons (time pressure usually being the winner).

It is however a fully supported feature of Visual Studio 2010 and should be visible in the first Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't se it in 2010, I just saw that I could coloring all the user types not one color for interfaces one for classes and so on.

Comment: Scrolling down you see User Types, User Types (Delegates), User Types (Enums), etc...

Comment: Please don't post comments as "answers".

Comment: Well those are only for C#,

there are one called User Types (Vb.NET) that is for vb.net the others are for C#